# adding an extra number to be sorted

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I was wondering how I could add an extra number to be sorted separate of the array, but to be added to the array in the end? So after the values of the array are entered by user we can try to add lets say X , which will also be entered by user after the initial array is entered, and then added to the end sorted array.
    #include

```
void main() {
    int i, j, num, temp, n;

    printf("\nPlease enter the size of the array:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int array[n];
    printf("Enter the numbers to be sorted one by one:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", & array[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < (n - i - 1); j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Sorted array is...\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you asking how to throw an additional number into the array *after* it is already sorted, and do so efficiently without having to resort the array?

Comment: yes i suppose. I was thinking that after the numbers for the array are input add a seperate value, say X and add that to the sorted array?

Comment: Ok. that is clearer and you may desire to take the time to update your question as such. Regardless, you likely want to do a *binary search* to find the place where the new item goes, then a *rotate* to shift all the elements from that point on upward in the array to make "a hole" for the new item to fill. The only part that requires comparisons is the search, and it is a divide-and-conquer algorithm. It should require O(logN) complexity for the search, and at-worst O(N) complexity for the rotate. There are other algorithms, but this is likely the one your prof is targeting.

Comment: Thank you very much, i just updated the question as such. now can i keep the initial program and then ad a binary search also, and if so where?

Comment: After the initial sort. There are lots of links on binary searching ordered sequences efficiently. Do some web-work. You'll find plant of info, and likely sample code as well. If you still have a problem with your implementation that seems to be a sticking point, bring it back here.

Comment: yeah ive tried looking and im still having alittle trouble trying ot apply it. i can searching portion but unfortunatly unable to put it back into the original array and print it.

Comment: `int array []` should have a size of `n + 1`. `X` can be added to element `array [n]`.